# Where do I find nameless items?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

The nameless items are the best in the game from what I can gather. I got a couple of nameless items, I think a pair of boots and a ring from a vendor. After doing some research I found a couple of threads of people talking about the nameless items in the extra last dungeon but nothing concrete as to where to find them exactly. Some people have said floor 3-6 but fail to say where exactly or what items I should be looking for.

Where can I find all of the nameless items for each of the characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only spot they drop from is the ex Dungeon.  The weapons are on the 6th floor only. The accessories are on the 5th floor only.  The rings, boots, armors all are between the first and third floors.  You can also get a ring and some boots from shop levels later in the game but all the rest is in the Ex Dungeon.